# Parse Error. unexpected end of file. (PHP)

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            if (($username=="x")AND($password=="y"))
            {
                echo "You are logged in as".$username.";
            }
        ?>
    </body> 
</html>
```

I get a parse error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN)
>   on line 17

Comment: I suggest using an IDE such as [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) - this will make simple errors like this much easier to spot

Answer (score 5):

Your `echo` use is incorrect, you have double quote `"` problem :

```
echo "You are logged in as " . $username;
```

See [echo examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You are either missin `"` or you have one more `"`

```
echo "You are logged in as".$username.";
```

Can become

```
echo "You are logged in as".$username."";
```

or

```
echo "You are logged in as".$username;
```

Or even better solution:

```
echo "You are logged in as {$username}";
```

And for better readibility of your code, dont use `AND`, use `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the completely fixed code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

            if (($username=="x")AND($password=="y"))
            { 
                echo "You are logged in as".$username;
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double quote (`"`) problem :

```
echo "You are logged in as".$username.";
```

You can do like this :

```
echo "You are logged in as {$username}";
```